# use of for loop for assigning a bit blasted signals to its vector in system verilog

Tags: for-loop, system-verilog

I am using a for loop to assign a bit blasted signal to its vector as follows:

```
for (int i=0;i<=255;i++)
primary_sig[i] =     test_bench.dut.u_top.u_chip_core_top.u_security_control_wrapper.u_security_control.\primary_sig[i] ;
```

But I am getting error. Can anyone pls help me why this loop is not working and what to do.
Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? I am not sure on the `.\` in your signal name.

Comment: The backslash (`` \ ``) in `.\primary_sig[i]` means literal "primary_sig[i]" where `i` is a ASCII character and not a variable reference. See [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 5.6.1 _Escaped identifiers_. Try removing the backslash.

Comment: @Greg: I think the OP is trying to reverse the bit-blasting effect. \primary_sig[i] (i from 0 to 255) seems to be a scalar variable declared as something like `logic \primary_sig[0], \primary_sig[1], ...`. If so, removing ``\`` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a good way in Verilog to achieve what you want. Because of the `\` character, the bit blasted signals that you are trying to assign to `primary_sig[i]` are each scalar, although they have `[i]` in their identifier, i.e., `i` is not an index.

Here is a simpler example: consider 5 signals `a_0, a_1, ..., a_4`. What you are asking is the following behavior (which does not work):

```
for (int i=0;i<=4 ;i++)
  primary_sig[i] = a_i;  // --> Doesn't work since i is part of the literal name
```

AFAIK, despite the generate-based solution reported [here](http://verificationguild.com/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&t=4785), generate blocks can only be uses for array indices, not for substituting literal names.

The only hack that I can think of is to write a script (e.g. in perl or your synthesis tool's tcl) to generate a statement like below automatically, and then copy it into your Verilog code.

```
primary_sig = {a_4, a_3, a_2, a_1, a_0};
```